# How to center input text in textfields?

Tags: codenameone

I am unable to center the input text in `textfield`s, it is always left aligned.

I have tried using `.getStyle().setAlignment(Component.CENTER)` on my `textfield`, however it crashes on compilation.

How do I center align the input text in `textfield`s?

Comment: What's the compilation error? Compilation doesn't "crash". Notice you should never use `getStyle()` and use `getUnselectedStyle` et al.

Comment: Hi,

now I am unable to recreate the problem, but if I remember correctly it was not a compilation as a said, it was upon rendering.

Anyhow, how should I do to center the text in the textfield? My textfield variable is called "password" and when I try the following code:
password.getUnselectedStyle().setAlignment(TextField.CENTER);
password.getSelectedStyle().setAlignment(TextField.CENTER);

Comment: the result is like this, the first printscreen is how the Textfield looks like unselected, the second printscreen is how the Textfield looks like when it is select

http://oskarrosen.com/random/center_textfield_input.PNG
http://oskarrosen.com/random/center_textfield_input_text.PNG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `getStyle()` which is a mistake.

You should use `getUnselectedStyle()`, `getSelectedStyle()` et al.
or alternatively use `getAllStyles()`.

However, centered text won't work during input as it requires the native underlying platform which does the editing to support that behavior. Unfortunately they are very inconsistent in that regard so we don't enable that.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body>
<input type="text" style="text-align:center" size=20 />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For clarification, I am using Codename One to develop mobile apps.

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".